# how to 'indexStorageMetadataOnlyForOversizedDocuments' to true?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-services

in Azure, when importing data  ( container ) , the task is failing because the PDF in the blob is too  big. Im prompted to set 'indexStorageMetadataOnlyForOversizedDocuments' to true, but where ?
Thanks
David

Comment: This parameter is part of blob configuration in indexer definition. How are you creating the indexer?

Comment: Hi, I select "add index" in the Cognitive Search Service blade.

Comment: I'm not sure if Azure Portal allows advanced configuration for an indexer but you can try editing the indexer to try it out there. Otherwise you can use REST API to update the indexer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/update-indexer. HTH.

Comment: I used PostMan and successfully updated the value, still same error message.